# Rewrite rule on URL query string

Tags: mod-rewrite

Can somebody help me how to replace query string URL. I want to redirect URL (my requirement to remove `%2Fcontent%2Fabc` from query string URL).

From :

```
http://something.com/en-US/login.html?resource=%2Fcontent%2Fabc%2Fen-US%2Fxyz.html&$$login$$=%24%24login%24%24
```

to:

```
http://something.com/en-US/login.html?resource=%2Fen-US%2Fxyz.html&$$login$$=%24%24login%24%24
```

I tried using rewrite condition and rule below but no luck.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^resource=%2Fcontent%2Fabc(.*)$       

RewriteRule ^/(.*)?resource=%2Fcontent%2Fabc(.*)$ /$1?resource=%2 [L]
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Please try to show you at least tried to solve the issue yourself first. -- help: http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Comment: I tried with this  but noting happening.                                                                                   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^resource=%2Fcontent%2Fabc(.*)$         
RewriteRule ^/(.*)?resource=%2Fcontent%2Fabc(.*)$    /$1?resource=%2 [L]

Comment: Edit the original post. And please use proper formatting for the code.

Comment: Thank you . I have edited the original post.